# find returning wrong results

Tags: playorm

I have the following mapped entity.

```
@NoSqlEntity
@NoSqlQueries({
        @NoSqlQuery(name = "findByName", query = "select u from TABLE as u where :name = u.name"),
        @NoSqlQuery(name = "findById", query = "select u from TABLE as u where :id = u.id"),
        @NoSqlQuery(name = "findByCpf", query = "select u from TABLE as u where :cpf = u.cpf"),
        @NoSqlQuery(name = "findAllUserIds", query = "select u from TABLE as u ") })
public class User {

    @NoSqlId
    @NoSqlIndexed
    @Field
    private String id;
    @NoSqlIndexed
    @Field
    private String cpf;
    @NoSqlEmbedded
    @Field
    private List<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();
    @NoSqlIndexed
    @Field
    private String name;
    @Field
    private Long facebookId;
```

Then I use the find method like follows:

```
Iterable<KeyValue<User>> iterable = UserDao.get().findAllUserIds();
        for (KeyValue<User> kv : iterable) {
            System.out.println("indexing user " + kv.getKey());
            IndexManager.get().updateIndex(kv.getValue());
        }
```

I have 5 users in my database, but this returns just 3 results. Am I doing something wrong, or did I find a bug?
Bellow I list the data stored in cassandra and the output of this sysout.

data stored in cassandra:

```
[default@dmp] list User;
Using default limit of 100
Using default column limit of 100
-------------------
RowKey: 12656382709:devel-PowerEdge-1850
=> (column=cpf, value=, timestamp=1351175983356001)
=> (column=facebookId, value=, timestamp=1351175983356001)
=> (column=name, value=6a6f616f, timestamp=1351175983356001)
-------------------
RowKey: 1
=> (column=cpf, value=, timestamp=1351175983442001)
=> (column=facebookId, value=, timestamp=1351175983442001)
=> (column=name, value=, timestamp=1351175983442001)
=> (column=publisherIds1, value=, timestamp=1351175983442001)
=> (column=publisherIds2, value=, timestamp=1351175983442001)
=> (column=publisherIds3, value=, timestamp=1351175983442001)
-------------------
RowKey: 25d3e5cd-7c30-4a56-8ad5-32642fd670a1
=> (column=cpf, value=323932383232393839383938, timestamp=1350583912807001)
=> (column=facebookId, value=536a, timestamp=1350583912807001)
=> (column=name, value=6a6f7365, timestamp=1350583912807001)
-------------------
RowKey: 12064304627:devel-PowerEdge-1850
=> (column=cpf, value=, timestamp=1350583912594001)
=> (column=facebookId, value=, timestamp=1350583912594001)
=> (column=name, value=6a6f616f, timestamp=1350583912594001)
-------------------
RowKey: 5a353a6f-62cc-4fd3-a58b-8ee1cc01bed3
=> (column=cpf, value=323932383232393839383938, timestamp=1351175983602001)
=> (column=facebookId, value=536a, timestamp=1351175983602001)
=> (column=name, value=6a6f7365, timestamp=1351175983602001)

5 Rows Returned.
Elapsed time: 335 msec(s).
[default@dmp]
```

log output:

```
...
INFO: On keyspace=dmpExisting column families=[inheritancetoone, partsecurity, forset, timeseriesdata, inheritancetoonespecific, stringindice, aapartitionedtrade, entitywithintkey, forcollection, entitywithdatetimekey, dbodatabasemeta, inheritancetomany, inheritancesuper, partitionedsingletrade, request, dbocolumnmeta, decimalindice, someentity, account, userplayorm, partaccount, integerindice, user, activity, dbotablemeta]
NOTE: WE WILL CREATE new column families automatically as you save entites that have no column family
...
INFO: [DboTableMeta]parsing query=findAll query=SELECT t FROM TABLE as t
2012-10-25 17:43:56,853 com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl setupQueryStuff
INFO: [DboTableMeta]parsing query=findLike query=SELECT t FROM TABLE as t WHERE t.columnFamily >= :prefix and t.columnFamily < :modifiedPrefix
2012-10-25 17:43:56,864 com.alvazan.orm.parser.antlr.Optimizer optimizeGtLtToBetween
INFO: optimizing query tree for varname=t.columnFamily
2012-10-25 17:43:56,869 com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl setupQueryStuff
INFO: [User]parsing query=findByName query=select u from TABLE as u where :name = u.name
2012-10-25 17:43:56,874 com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl setupQueryStuff
INFO: [User]parsing query=findById query=select u from TABLE as u where :id = u.id
2012-10-25 17:43:56,875 com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl setupQueryStuff
INFO: [User]parsing query=findByCpf query=select u from TABLE as u where :cpf = u.cpf
2012-10-25 17:43:56,877 com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl setupQueryStuff
INFO: [User]parsing query=findAllUserIds query=select u from TABLE as u 
2012-10-25 17:43:56,877 com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl rescan
INFO: Finished scanning classes, saving meta data
2012-10-25 17:43:56,883 com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.cassandra.ColumnFamilyHelper tryToLoadColumnFamilyImpl
INFO: Column family NOT found in-memory=DboDatabaseMeta, CHECK and LOAD from Cassandra if available
2012-10-25 17:43:56,884 com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.cassandra.ColumnFamilyHelper loadFromInMemoryOrDb
INFO: looking up meta=DboDatabaseMeta so we can add table to memory(one time operation)
2012-10-25 17:43:56,884 com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.cassandra.ColumnFamilyHelper loadFromInMemoryOrDb
INFO: found meta=DboDatabaseMeta locally
2012-10-25 17:43:56,884 com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.cassandra.ColumnFamilyHelper tryToLoadColumnFamilyImpl
INFO: Virt CF=DboDatabaseMeta already exists and real colfamily=DboDatabaseMeta already exists so return it
2012-10-25 17:43:56,885 com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.cassandra.ColumnFamilyHelper tryToLoadColumnFamilyVirt
INFO: Total time to LOAD column family meta from cassandra=2
2012-10-25 17:43:57,052 com.alvazan.orm.logging.LogBatchFetch logInfo
INFO: [rawlogger]CF=[tablename=DboDatabaseMeta] Find took=164 ms for batchSize=500 numFetched=1
2012-10-25 17:43:57,107 com.alvazan.orm.layer5.nosql.cache.NoSqlReadCacheImpl fromCache
INFO: cache hit(need to optimize this even further)
2012-10-25 17:43:57,161 com.alvazan.orm.logging.NoSqlRawLogger logInformationImpl
INFO: [rawlogger] Data being flushed to database in one go=
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/owner][indexval=User,to pk=User:requests]
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/columnName][indexval=requests,to pk=User:requests]
CF=[tablename=DboColumnMeta] persist rowkey=User:requests
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/owner][indexval=User,to pk=User:publisherIds]
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/columnName][indexval=publisherIds,to pk=User:publisherIds]
CF=[tablename=DboColumnMeta] persist rowkey=User:publisherIds
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/owner][indexval=User,to pk=User:urls]
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/columnName][indexval=urls,to pk=User:urls]
CF=[tablename=DboColumnMeta] persist rowkey=User:urls
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/owner][indexval=User,to pk=User:name]
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/columnName][indexval=name,to pk=User:name]
CF=[tablename=DboColumnMeta] persist rowkey=User:name
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/owner][indexval=User,to pk=User:facebookId]
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/columnName][indexval=facebookId,to pk=User:facebookId]
CF=[tablename=DboColumnMeta] persist rowkey=User:facebookId
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/owner][indexval=User,to pk=User:cpf]
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/columnName][indexval=cpf,to pk=User:cpf]
CF=[tablename=DboColumnMeta] persist rowkey=User:cpf
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/owner][indexval=User,to pk=User:activitiesCursor]
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/columnName][indexval=activitiesCursor,to pk=User:activitiesCursor]
CF=[tablename=DboColumnMeta] persist rowkey=User:activitiesCursor
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/owner][indexval=User,to pk=User:id]
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/columnName][indexval=id,to pk=User:id]
CF=[tablename=DboColumnMeta] persist rowkey=User:id
CF=DboTableMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboTableMeta])=[rowkey=/DboTableMeta/columnFamily] (table found, colmeta not found)
CF=[tablename=DboTableMeta] persist rowkey=User
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/owner][indexval=Request,to pk=Request:user]
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/columnName][indexval=user,to pk=Request:user]
CF=[tablename=DboColumnMeta] persist rowkey=Request:user
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/owner][indexval=Request,to pk=Request:jSon]
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/columnName][indexval=jSon,to pk=Request:jSon]
CF=[tablename=DboColumnMeta] persist rowkey=Request:jSon
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/owner][indexval=Request,to pk=Request:strDate]
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/columnName][indexval=strDate,to pk=Request:strDate]
CF=[tablename=DboColumnMeta] persist rowkey=Request:strDate
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/owner][indexval=Request,to pk=Request:id]
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/columnName][indexval=id,to pk=Request:id]
CF=[tablename=DboColumnMeta] persist rowkey=Request:id
CF=DboTableMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboTableMeta])=[rowkey=/DboTableMeta/columnFamily] (table found, colmeta not found)
CF=[tablename=DboTableMeta] persist rowkey=Request
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/owner][indexval=DboColumnMeta,to pk=DboColumnMeta:collectionType]
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/columnName][indexval=collectionType,to pk=DboColumnMeta:collectionType]
CF=[tablename=DboColumnMeta] persist rowkey=DboColumnMeta:collectionType
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/owner][indexval=DboColumnMeta,to pk=DboColumnMeta:columnValueType]
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/columnName][indexval=columnValueType,to pk=DboColumnMeta:columnValueType]
CF=[tablename=DboColumnMeta] persist rowkey=DboColumnMeta:columnValueType
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/owner][indexval=DboColumnMeta,to pk=DboColumnMeta:itemType]
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/columnName][indexval=itemType,to pk=DboColumnMeta:itemType]
CF=[tablename=DboColumnMeta] persist rowkey=DboColumnMeta:itemType
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/owner][indexval=DboColumnMeta,to pk=DboColumnMeta:fkToColumnFamily]
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/columnName][indexval=fkToColumnFamily,to pk=DboColumnMeta:fkToColumnFamily]
CF=[tablename=DboColumnMeta] persist rowkey=DboColumnMeta:fkToColumnFamily
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/owner][indexval=DboColumnMeta,to pk=DboColumnMeta:owner]
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/columnName][indexval=owner,to pk=DboColumnMeta:owner]
CF=[tablename=DboColumnMeta] persist rowkey=DboColumnMeta:owner
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/owner][indexval=DboColumnMeta,to pk=DboColumnMeta:isPartitionedByThisColumn]
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/columnName][indexval=isPartitionedByThisColumn,to pk=DboColumnMeta:isPartitionedByThisColumn]
CF=[tablename=DboColumnMeta] persist rowkey=DboColumnMeta:isPartitionedByThisColumn
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/owner][indexval=DboColumnMeta,to pk=DboColumnMeta:columnName]
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/columnName][indexval=columnName,to pk=DboColumnMeta:columnName]
CF=[tablename=DboColumnMeta] persist rowkey=DboColumnMeta:columnName
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/owner][indexval=DboColumnMeta,to pk=DboColumnMeta:isIndexed]
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/columnName][indexval=isIndexed,to pk=DboColumnMeta:isIndexed]
CF=[tablename=DboColumnMeta] persist rowkey=DboColumnMeta:isIndexed
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/owner][indexval=DboColumnMeta,to pk=DboColumnMeta:isSeparateRow]
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/columnName][indexval=isSeparateRow,to pk=DboColumnMeta:isSeparateRow]
CF=[tablename=DboColumnMeta] persist rowkey=DboColumnMeta:isSeparateRow
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/owner][indexval=DboColumnMeta,to pk=DboColumnMeta:foreignKeyToExtensions]
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/columnName][indexval=foreignKeyToExtensions,to pk=DboColumnMeta:foreignKeyToExtensions]
CF=[tablename=DboColumnMeta] persist rowkey=DboColumnMeta:foreignKeyToExtensions
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/owner][indexval=DboColumnMeta,to pk=DboColumnMeta:id]
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/columnName][indexval=id,to pk=DboColumnMeta:id]
CF=[tablename=DboColumnMeta] persist rowkey=DboColumnMeta:id
CF=DboTableMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboTableMeta])=[rowkey=/DboTableMeta/columnFamily] (table found, colmeta not found)
CF=[tablename=DboTableMeta] persist rowkey=DboColumnMeta
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/owner][indexval=RequestStru,to pk=RequestStru:user]
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/columnName][indexval=user,to pk=RequestStru:user]
CF=[tablename=DboColumnMeta] persist rowkey=RequestStru:user
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/owner][indexval=RequestStru,to pk=RequestStru:jSon]
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/columnName][indexval=jSon,to pk=RequestStru:jSon]
CF=[tablename=DboColumnMeta] persist rowkey=RequestStru:jSon
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/owner][indexval=RequestStru,to pk=RequestStru:strDate]
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/columnName][indexval=strDate,to pk=RequestStru:strDate]
CF=[tablename=DboColumnMeta] persist rowkey=RequestStru:strDate
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/owner][indexval=RequestStru,to pk=RequestStru:id]
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/columnName][indexval=id,to pk=RequestStru:id]
CF=[tablename=DboColumnMeta] persist rowkey=RequestStru:id
CF=DboTableMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboTableMeta])=[rowkey=/DboTableMeta/columnFamily] (table found, colmeta not found)
CF=[tablename=DboTableMeta] persist rowkey=RequestStru
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/owner][indexval=DboTableMeta,to pk=DboTableMeta:nameToField]
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/columnName][indexval=nameToField,to pk=DboTableMeta:nameToField]
CF=[tablename=DboColumnMeta] persist rowkey=DboTableMeta:nameToField
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/owner][indexval=DboTableMeta,to pk=DboTableMeta:colNamePrefixType]
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/columnName][indexval=colNamePrefixType,to pk=DboTableMeta:colNamePrefixType]
CF=[tablename=DboColumnMeta] persist rowkey=DboTableMeta:colNamePrefixType
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/owner][indexval=DboTableMeta,to pk=DboTableMeta:colNameType]
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/columnName][indexval=colNameType,to pk=DboTableMeta:colNameType]
CF=[tablename=DboColumnMeta] persist rowkey=DboTableMeta:colNameType
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/owner][indexval=DboTableMeta,to pk=DboTableMeta:isEmbeddable]
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/columnName][indexval=isEmbeddable,to pk=DboTableMeta:isEmbeddable]
CF=[tablename=DboColumnMeta] persist rowkey=DboTableMeta:isEmbeddable
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/owner][indexval=DboTableMeta,to pk=DboTableMeta:actualColFamily]
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/columnName][indexval=actualColFamily,to pk=DboTableMeta:actualColFamily]
CF=[tablename=DboColumnMeta] persist rowkey=DboTableMeta:actualColFamily
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/owner][indexval=DboTableMeta,to pk=DboTableMeta:foreignKeyToExtensions]
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/columnName][indexval=foreignKeyToExtensions,to pk=DboTableMeta:foreignKeyToExtensions]
CF=[tablename=DboColumnMeta] persist rowkey=DboTableMeta:foreignKeyToExtensions
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/owner][indexval=DboTableMeta,to pk=DboTableMeta:idColumn]
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/columnName][indexval=idColumn,to pk=DboTableMeta:idColumn]
CF=[tablename=DboColumnMeta] persist rowkey=DboTableMeta:idColumn
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/owner][indexval=DboTableMeta,to pk=DboTableMeta:columnFamily]
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/columnName][indexval=columnFamily,to pk=DboTableMeta:columnFamily]
CF=[tablename=DboColumnMeta] persist rowkey=DboTableMeta:columnFamily
CF=DboTableMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboTableMeta])=[rowkey=/DboTableMeta/columnFamily] (table found, colmeta not found)
CF=[tablename=DboTableMeta] persist rowkey=DboTableMeta
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/owner][indexval=DboDatabaseMeta,to pk=DboDatabaseMeta:colFamilyToMeta]
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/columnName][indexval=colFamilyToMeta,to pk=DboDatabaseMeta:colFamilyToMeta]
CF=[tablename=DboColumnMeta] persist rowkey=DboDatabaseMeta:colFamilyToMeta
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/owner][indexval=DboDatabaseMeta,to pk=DboDatabaseMeta:id]
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/columnName][indexval=id,to pk=DboDatabaseMeta:id]
CF=[tablename=DboColumnMeta] persist rowkey=DboDatabaseMeta:id
CF=DboTableMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboTableMeta])=[rowkey=/DboTableMeta/columnFamily] (table found, colmeta not found)
CF=[tablename=DboTableMeta] persist rowkey=DboDatabaseMeta
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/owner][indexval=StringIndice,to pk=StringIndice:id]
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/columnName][indexval=id,to pk=StringIndice:id]
CF=[tablename=DboColumnMeta] persist rowkey=StringIndice:id
CF=DboTableMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboTableMeta])=[rowkey=/DboTableMeta/columnFamily] (table found, colmeta not found)
CF=[tablename=DboTableMeta] persist rowkey=StringIndice
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/owner][indexval=DecimalIndice,to pk=DecimalIndice:id]
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/columnName][indexval=id,to pk=DecimalIndice:id]
CF=[tablename=DboColumnMeta] persist rowkey=DecimalIndice:id
CF=DboTableMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboTableMeta])=[rowkey=/DboTableMeta/columnFamily] (table found, colmeta not found)
CF=[tablename=DboTableMeta] persist rowkey=DecimalIndice
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/owner][indexval=IntegerIndice,to pk=IntegerIndice:id]
CF=DboColumnMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboColumnMeta])=[rowkey=/DboColumnMeta/columnName][indexval=id,to pk=IntegerIndice:id]
CF=[tablename=DboColumnMeta] persist rowkey=IntegerIndice:id
CF=DboTableMeta index persist(cf=[tablename=DboTableMeta])=[rowkey=/DboTableMeta/columnFamily] (table found, colmeta not found)
CF=[tablename=DboTableMeta] persist rowkey=IntegerIndice
CF=[tablename=DboDatabaseMeta] persist rowkey=nosqlorm
2012-10-25 17:43:57,168 com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.cassandra.ColumnFamilyHelper tryToLoadColumnFamilyImpl
INFO: Column family NOT found in-memory=StringIndice, CHECK and LOAD from Cassandra if available
2012-10-25 17:43:57,169 com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.cassandra.ColumnFamilyHelper loadFromInMemoryOrDb
INFO: looking up meta=StringIndice so we can add table to memory(one time operation)
2012-10-25 17:43:57,169 com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.cassandra.ColumnFamilyHelper loadFromInMemoryOrDb
INFO: found meta=StringIndice locally
2012-10-25 17:43:57,170 com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.cassandra.ColumnFamilyHelper tryToLoadColumnFamilyImpl
INFO: Virt CF=StringIndice already exists and real colfamily=StringIndice already exists so return it
2012-10-25 17:43:57,171 com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.cassandra.ColumnFamilyHelper tryToLoadColumnFamilyVirt
INFO: Total time to LOAD column family meta from cassandra=3
2012-10-25 17:43:57,183 com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.cassandra.ColumnFamilyHelper tryToLoadColumnFamilyImpl
INFO: Column family NOT found in-memory=DboColumnMeta, CHECK and LOAD from Cassandra if available
2012-10-25 17:43:57,183 com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.cassandra.ColumnFamilyHelper loadFromInMemoryOrDb
INFO: looking up meta=DboColumnMeta so we can add table to memory(one time operation)
2012-10-25 17:43:57,184 com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.cassandra.ColumnFamilyHelper loadFromInMemoryOrDb
INFO: found meta=DboColumnMeta locally
2012-10-25 17:43:57,184 com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.cassandra.ColumnFamilyHelper tryToLoadColumnFamilyImpl
INFO: Virt CF=DboColumnMeta already exists and real colfamily=DboColumnMeta already exists so return it
2012-10-25 17:43:57,184 com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.cassandra.ColumnFamilyHelper tryToLoadColumnFamilyVirt
INFO: Total time to LOAD column family meta from cassandra=1
2012-10-25 17:43:57,187 com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.cassandra.ColumnFamilyHelper tryToLoadColumnFamilyImpl
INFO: Column family NOT found in-memory=DboTableMeta, CHECK and LOAD from Cassandra if available
2012-10-25 17:43:57,188 com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.cassandra.ColumnFamilyHelper loadFromInMemoryOrDb
INFO: looking up meta=DboTableMeta so we can add table to memory(one time operation)
2012-10-25 17:43:57,188 com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.cassandra.ColumnFamilyHelper loadFromInMemoryOrDb
INFO: found meta=DboTableMeta locally
2012-10-25 17:43:57,188 com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.cassandra.ColumnFamilyHelper tryToLoadColumnFamilyImpl
INFO: Virt CF=DboTableMeta already exists and real colfamily=DboTableMeta already exists so return it
2012-10-25 17:43:57,189 com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.cassandra.ColumnFamilyHelper tryToLoadColumnFamilyVirt
INFO: Total time to LOAD column family meta from cassandra=2
2012-10-25 17:43:57,294 com.alvazan.orm.logging.NoSqlRawLogger sendChanges
INFO: [rawlogger] Sending Changes to server took(including spi plugin)=131 ms
2012-10-25 17:43:57,296 com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl rescan
INFO: Finished saving meta data, complelety done initializing
2012-10-25 17:43:57,297 com.alvazan.orm.logging.NoSqlRawLogger logColScanImpl
INFO: [rawlogger]CF=[tablename=User] index=/User/cpf(in CF=StringIndice) scanning index for value in range:ALL DATA with batchSize=null
2012-10-25 17:43:57,307 com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.cassandra.ColumnFamilyHelper tryToLoadColumnFamilyImpl
INFO: Column family NOT found in-memory=User, CHECK and LOAD from Cassandra if available
2012-10-25 17:43:57,308 com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.cassandra.ColumnFamilyHelper loadFromInMemoryOrDb
INFO: looking up meta=User so we can add table to memory(one time operation)
2012-10-25 17:43:57,308 com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.cassandra.ColumnFamilyHelper loadFromInMemoryOrDb
INFO: found meta=User locally
2012-10-25 17:43:57,309 com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.cassandra.ColumnFamilyHelper tryToLoadColumnFamilyImpl
INFO: Virt CF=User already exists and real colfamily=User already exists so return it
2012-10-25 17:43:57,309 com.alvazan.orm.layer9z.spi.db.cassandra.ColumnFamilyHelper tryToLoadColumnFamilyVirt
INFO: Total time to LOAD column family meta from cassandra=2
2012-10-25 17:43:57,359 com.alvazan.orm.logging.LogBatchFetch logInfo
INFO: [rawlogger]CF=[tablename=User] index=/User/cpf Index slice took=47 ms for batchSize=all numFetched=3
2012-10-25 17:43:57,430 com.alvazan.orm.logging.LogBatchFetch logInfo
INFO: [rawlogger]CF=[tablename=User] Find took=67 ms for batchSize=500 numFetched=3
2012-10-25 17:43:57,441 com.alvazan.orm.logging.NoSqlRawLogger logColScanImpl
INFO: [rawlogger]CF=[tablename=User] index=/User/activitiesCursor/1(in CF=StringIndice) scanning index for value in range:ALL DATA with batchSize=200
indexing user 1
2012-10-25 17:43:57,588 org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientUtil createClient
INFO: Creating new http client, config:maxConnections=128&maxConnectionsPerHost=32&followRedirects=false
2012-10-25 17:44:03,495 com.alvazan.orm.logging.NoSqlRawLogger logColScanImpl
INFO: [rawlogger]CF=[tablename=User] index=/User/activitiesCursor/12656382709:devel-PowerEdge-1850(in CF=StringIndice) scanning index for value in range:ALL DATA with batchSize=200
indexing user 12656382709:devel-PowerEdge-1850
2012-10-25 17:44:03,645 com.alvazan.orm.logging.NoSqlRawLogger logColScanImpl
INFO: [rawlogger]CF=[tablename=User] index=/User/activitiesCursor/5a353a6f-62cc-4fd3-a58b-8ee1cc01bed3(in CF=StringIndice) scanning index for value in range:ALL DATA with batchSize=200
indexing user 5a353a6f-62cc-4fd3-a58b-8ee1cc01bed3
```

Comment: If you add more relevant tags you're much more likely to get an answer.

Comment: I usually would, but this is really too specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the logs are missing when you actually saved those entities.  I assume you are saving all the entities through PlayOrm api, correct?  but the Users must have been saved in another run of the system, not this run or there is other logs I would see and could analyze to see if there was a problem.

NOTE: Another cause is if you put the entities in BEFORE adding the @NoSqlIndexed annotation.  It is always good to have every entity have at least one field with @NoSqlIndexed annotation such that you can use the command line tool to reindex off of another index.

You can also view the index with the command line tool as well to see it's contents.